# disk defragmentation using powershell in 32bit

Tags: windows, powershell, x86, environment

I am getting one error while performing below command
`Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter C -Defrag -Verbose` .I'm getting error like **This command is not supported on x86 running in x64 environment** while i'm performing this operation on another computer. This command is working fine in both client side and server side but when I have to run it from server to perform in client side it shows this error. I want to know the problem and solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because you are trying to execute a command that requires 32 bit computing in a 64 bit shell.

When you search for PowerShell on the system you wish to execute the command on you should see both a 32 bit and a 64 bit version of Powershell:
[image]

Since you are running a 64 bit system, you most likely default to running the command in the 64 bit shell.

You need to select the `Windows PowerShell (x86)` to run it from the 32 bit shell, and thus be compliant with the command you are trying to execute.

If you call PowerShell from a scheduel task or in your case Python, you need to call it from the 32 bit PowerShell location:

```
%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

In order to use this in python to call a PowerShell script you could do something like this:

```
psxmlgen = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe',
                             '-ExecutionPolicy',
                             'Unrestricted',
                             './buildxml.ps1',
                             arg1, arg2, arg3], cwd=os.getcwd())
result = psxmlgen.wait()
```

You may not need the Execution Policy nor the arguments depending on the script you want to call.